# save customer account field whenever address object saved

Tags: event-observer, customer, address, enterprise-1.14

The following observer calling properly.I'm getting address ,customer object also .

but customer setting data not working(3rd line).even i tried save function on that.but it is also not working. 
even i changed event name `customer_address_save_before`.
here i created customer attribute company.

**can you help any one?**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Gumbrands_Officename>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Gumbrands_Officename>
  </modules>
    <global><models>
            <officename>
                <class>Gumbrands_Officename_Model</class>
            </officename>
        </models>
<events>
<customer_address_save_after>
            <observers>
                <Officename>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>officename/observer</class>
                    <method>updateCompany1</method>
                </Officename>
            </observers>
        </customer_address_save_after>
</events>
</global>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php
class Gumbrands_Officename_Model_Observer
{  
    public function updateCompany1($observer)
    { 

   $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
   $customer= $address->getCustomer();
   $customer->setData('company', $address->getData('company'));

    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: please try to remove cache and try i have same problem occur before

Comment: i removed cache.not working.

Comment: have you add new  field  company to customer?

Comment: added.there is no problem with field name.that is sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `update the attribute using Resource model` because of when you have `using save()` function  of `customer model` then customer `will also call customer address model  save function` that make `loop.`If you use `getResource()->saveAttribute()` function that only update `only specific field` that means it does not  `call address model save function`

```
$customer->setData('company', $address->getData('company'));
$customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer,'company');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::setAttribute()

Comment: please check...  i have update the answer

Comment: upvote your answer

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems to be ok. The one thing that is missing is calling the `save` method

```
<?php
class Gumbrands_Officename_Model_Observer
{  
    public function updateCompany1($observer)
    { 

   $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
   $customer= $address->getCustomer();
    $customer->setData('company', $address->getData('company'));
    $customer->save();
    } 
}
```

Comment: i mentioned "even i tried save function on that.but it is also not working" in question.the browser continuously loading.after some time it is stopped.

Comment: ahhhh right, because it's calling the address save from the customer save. Ok let me see